# PHP Soap Request foreach

Tags: php, soap, request

I have a Souap Request and I do not know how I can go through all VoucherCodeItems with foreach.
I tried this, but it dosn't work:

```
foreach($response->VoucherCodeCollection->VoucherCodeItem AS $key => $val) {
 echo "Feld $key hat den Wert: $val<br>";
}
```

This is what i get when make a print like:

```
print_r($response);
```

Result

```
stdClass Object
(
    [TotalResults] => 2
    [VoucherCodeCollection] => stdClass Object
        (
            [VoucherCodeItem] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 215523
                            [ProgramId] => 6767
                            [Code] => 
                            [Title] => Adventskalender
                            [Description] => Im Adventskalender
                        )
                    [1] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [Id] => 215453
                            [ProgramId] => 8476
                            [Code] => 
                            [Title] => Wir schenken dir 15 EUR!!
                            [Description] => 
                        )


                )

        )

)
```

Comment: `$val` is just yet anothe object, use `->` notation to access its properties.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly echo out the object:

Try:

```
foreach ($response->VoucherCodeCollection->VoucherCodeItem as $key => $val) {
 echo "Feld $key hat den Wert: {$val->Title}<br>";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that helps :)